# AIX java.net.SocketException: A system call received a parameter that is not valid

Tags: java, aix

I am really stuck with an AIX java issue.  I have an issue here that doesn't match other issues on SO and on the Web.

My application code runs fine on another AIX server with the same exact JRE - IBM AIX Java 1.8, but does not run on the server that I need it to.

Both servers are AIX 7.1, running the same JAR and same JRE from the same tarball.

I'm getting the following error when using a Spring RestTemplate.exchange() to retrieve and unmarshal some JSON.

It must be a server configuration issue, but I'm very stuck and would appreciate any help!

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: A system call received a parameter that is not valid.
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:127)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:181)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.a.a(a.java:209)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.a.b(a.java:41)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.a.a(a.java:193)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:268)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:745)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.e.read(e.java:56)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:257)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:297)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:356)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(ChunkedInputStream.java:564)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(ChunkedInputStream.java:621)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:708)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:144)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3352)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:144)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:197)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.loadMore(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.parseEscapedName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1749)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.slowParseName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1654)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._parseName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1484)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:700)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:120)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:149)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:18)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2993)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2158)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:222)
```

Comment: Since the JREs are identical I'd first start by ensuring that both AIX systems have exactly the same OS patch level (or whatever IBM calls it) installed.  There's probably something subtly different between the two systems.  Or, the message could be wrong and there's a hardware problem somewhere.  Did you check the system event logs for any issues?

Comment: This is a bug in IBM's JDK and should be submitted to IBM.

Comment: (Java-frameworks are known to not handle network problems properly; in real life, connection losses are normal, they should be handled without much ado.)

Answer (score -1):

It's probably a firewall issue.
Communication is cut abruptly by some sort of firewall, so the socket is closed by the OS, which gives error when you try to read from it.